# How to handle form error validations in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-form-validation

I am new to Angular and in my form I have three fields **Name**, **email** and **radio section**. My requirement is:

- when I select name radio button Name input field is required
- when I select email radio button Email input field is required

I tried, but no result. How can I implement this requirement?

### .html:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="emailForm">

    <!-- Name -->
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="name" [required]="radioModel=='1'">
             <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
             <mat-error *ngIf="emailForm.get('name').hasError('required')">
               Name is <strong>required</strong>
             </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  
  <!-- Email -->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="email" [required]="radioModel=='2'">
    <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailForm.get('email').hasError && !emailForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>


<!-- Radio Button -->
<div class="radion-button">
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="radioGroup" [(ngModel)]="radioModel">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Name</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Email</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-error *ngIf="emailForm.get('radioGroup').hasError('required') && emailForm.get('radioGroup').touched">
               Selection is <strong>required</strong>
             </mat-error>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>
</form>
```

### .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

/** @title Input with a custom ErrorStateMatcher */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-error-state-matcher-example',
  templateUrl: './input-error-state-matcher-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-error-state-matcher-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample {
  emailForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    //Form Group
    this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
      email:new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      name:new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      radioGroup:new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
    });
  }
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
}
```

My code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-yfxnps

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @ user184994 my code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-yfxnps

Comment: @ user184994 i pasted my code

Comment: Thank you, try the code below

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `Validators.required` from the TS file, it should work

```
this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
  email:new FormControl('', [Validators.email]),
  name:new FormControl('', []),
  radioGroup:new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
});
```

**[Here is a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-qhbzjj?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts)**

Comment: One small problem error message showing when i touched on field but when i select  radio button error message need to show

Comment: @AbhiRam In that case, remove `(control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted)` from your ErrorStateMatcher

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add validations to FormControls using setValidators based on condition.

```
this.emailForm.get('radioGroup').valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
      if(value === '1'){
        this.emailForm.get('name').setValidators(Validators.required);
        this.emailForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
        alert('name is required');
      }else if(value === '2'){
        this.emailForm.get('email').setValidators(Validators.required);
        this.emailForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
        alert('email is required');
      }
    });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-m5gnzz

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ahmedtamseer/tn-form-error) package. Its simple easy to use and customize for both reactive and template driven forms.

Code snippet:

*HTML*

```
<form [formGroup]="demoForm">
    <div>
         <label for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" placeholder="Name validator">
         <tn-form-error [control]="demoForm.controls.name" [field]="'Name'"></tn-form-error>
    </div>
</form>
```

*Component*

```
<p>
 this.demoForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''[Validators.required])
 });
```

Play around [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tn-form-error)